# The child class does not call code of the parent class

Tags: python

The child class does not call code of the parent class.
I wrote this code. I thought the Id field of the Extension2 class would be 2, but it is 1

```
myvariable = 0
lock = threading.Lock()


def get_next_id() -> int:
    global myvariable
    global lock
    with lock:
        myvariable += 1
        return myvariable


class Extension:
    Id = get_next_id()


class Extension2(Extension):
    pass
```

[image]

Comment: `Id` is a class variable, not an instance variable, as you've written it. If you come from Java or C++, you can think of it like a `static` variable. There's only one of them.

Comment: I know. I want each child class to have its own unique Id

Comment: Assignment to class variables happen when the class is defined. Defining a subclass doesn't re-execute them, so it doesn't get a new Id, it just inherits the id from the parent.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I think I understand your problem better now. See if my answer makes sense for your use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Defining `Id` in the parent class only defines it once. Children *inherit* this value, but the expression isn't re-evaluated. You can use [`__init_subclass__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation) to force evaluation on every subclass, sort of like `__init__` does for instances.

```
class Extension:
    Id = get_next_id()

    @classmethod
    def __init_subclass__(cls):
        cls.Id = get_next_id()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZDNboMwDMfvfgofQdOqtbtV6rRLD5P6DlEgKVgLCUpMP56emXQCVs0n@2f774/@zm3w7@MI1PUhMnIbrTbkG4DuftGRdOUsHvANXKi/xZkLNicBRQkAxp6xsay8vbEiU5T4@oHkeQ8o1rhQaYeL2ppOojm@Erc5ejRNtpr/csDtzKPlIfq1IEDtdEp4vLH1iYJ/iHwZ2ffPYpD5Z67urJxuMpgOUIo8sUpDlbNKFbVL5bKNRJv/BJ9H74rZ/e3uJS91fZSXLEkRK5/ZLsNx/AE)

Answer (score 0):

The way you have structured your class, `Id` is not an instance variable for the class. You probably want to use `__init__` to initialize data members of a class. For example:

```
def set_variable():
    return "id"

class Extension():
    def __init__(self):
        self.Id = set_variable()

class Extension2(Extension):
    pass
```

Then when you create class instances, their members are automatically assigned, and this is true of the child class as well, which will inherit instance variables of the parent unless you specify otherwise.

```
r = Extension()
s = Extension2()
```

`r.Id` and `s.Id` will both be set to "id"